# Future of Pooled Mining

Tags: mining-pools, solo-mining

What do people think lies in store for the future of mining coins from the point of view of both pooled mining and mining individually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My assessment is that Mining Pools are the only mining operations that will exist and their fees will make the pool operators money, but the actual miners will only know Booms & Busts as the spot price, electricity costs, difficulty, etc will always vary.

If you want to make money in the mining world, your best option is to start a pool.